# Reuse Bundle Symfony2

Tags: symfony

This seems like it should be easy, but I am unable to find the answer. How can one reuse a bundle multiple times within the same symfony project? For example if I have an article bundle that I want to use multiple times on the same website.

I see in the app routing.yml you can add a prefix to the routed URL's, however if I try this multiple times with a different prefix each time only the last one works. Assumedly because the unique route names within the bundle are not prefixed, just the routs.

```
Foo:
    resource: "@Foo/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /bar/

Bah:
    resource: "@Foo/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /bah/
```

So where do I go from here? Is there some way to auto prefix unique route names, database tables etc (while still being able to reference / link to everything from within templates). Or is this a situation that symfony has just not been designed to accommodate?

Comment: Anyone have any ideas here? This is pretty much a deal breaker for me to build an application in this framework. Am hoping I haven't just wasted two weeks of my life learning it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that there are two options:

- Create the object in the your bundle:
  Inside of your foo controller, do something like this:

  `use Acme\BahBundle\Class;`

You should then be able to call it

```
$class = new Class();
$class->function('params');
```

- The other option is to register the bundle as a service, check out the doc for more info:

http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/service_container.html

Comment: If that doesn't help and you want to post a little more of your code here I'd be happy to take a look at it, i'm new to Symfony as well so the more examples and problems I come across the better :-)